# Emacs: Tabular `customize` entries?

Tags: emacs, elisp, customization

By default, every primitive item in the `customize` interface for a `defcustom` variable is on a new line, e.g.

```
[INS] [DEL] Keymaps:  f90-mode , fortran-mode , emacs-lisp-mode
            Repeat:
            [INS] [DEL] Key sequence: C-x C-x m
                        Command: forward-line
            [INS] [DEL] Key sequence: C-x C-x x
                        Command: end-of-line
            [INS] [DEL] Key sequence: C-x C-x 1
                        Command: right-char
            [INS] [DEL] Key sequence: C-x C-x 2
                        Command: left-char
            [INS]
[INS] [DEL] Keymaps:  fundamental-mode , global
            Repeat:
            [INS] [DEL] Key sequence: C-x C-x 9
                        Command: previous-line
            [INS]
[INS] [DEL]
```

Is it possible to obtain instead a tabular interface? The same variable should then look something like

```
[INS] [DEL] Keymaps:  f90-mode , fortran-mode , emacs-lisp-mode
            Repeat:
            [INS] [DEL] C-x C-x m       forward-line
            [INS] [DEL] C-x C-x x       end-of-line
            [INS] [DEL] C-x C-x 1       right-char
            [INS] [DEL] C-x C-x 2       left-char
            [INS]
[INS] [DEL] Keymaps:  fundamental-mode , global
            Repeat:
            [INS] [DEL] C-x C-x 9       previous-line
            [INS]
[INS] [DEL]
```

For completeness: The data given here is junk-data I use for testing. The `:type` of the variable is

```
     (alist 
      :key-type 
      (string :tag "Keymaps" :value "global")
      :value-type 
      (repeat 
       (group key-sequence (function :tag "Command"))))
```

Currently the only workaround I can think of is using a

```
(alist ...
 (repeat (string :tag "Key and Binding")))
```

type where users would enter key-sequence and binding in a predetermined format -- but that would border on defeating the purpose of the customize interface in the first place.

Comment: The answer will probably involve the `:format` keyword, described in the ["Type keywords" section of the elisp manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Type-Keywords.html).

Comment: Tried that. The `:format` keyword doesn't allow suppressing the trailing line break and indentation. That part seems to be done automatically.

Comment: I also checked the `:format` of the composite types `repeat` and `group` with the same lack of success.